# Should i be using UIAlertView or a custom view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I was wondering if Apple accepted that the UIAlertView be used as a custom view because I would like to add a UITextField to the UIAlertView or do they want UIAlertView only to be used to give users a warning/information.
Should I be using UIAlertView or create a custom view?

Some details about the view I want to create:

My view would have just like the UIAlertView a title, message, 2 buttons (1 to cancel and 1 to accept) and a textfield to enter an ip adress which would be returned.

If possible keep it to iOS 4.0 please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the class-documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

UIAlertView supports a text-field by default (take a look at textFieldAtIndex:).

So of course you can use it to get input from your users

Comment: Yeah is there any equivalent to textFieldAtIndex: for iOs 4.0?

Comment: Oh, no :). There you have to add a textfield by yourself but that is no problem, too. I did this for an older app of mine, too ;).

Comment: Yeah I thought so :) So I just add a UITextField with a CGRect frame and put some \n\n in my message string to give some space to the textField?

Comment: @Ben Lefebvre If, and your comment suggests so, you want to address iOS versions before 5.0, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not reject such modifications to facts such as these. Anyways , if you want to add a `UITextField` to a `UIAlertView` then it is already by default. You can make any number of changes in your `UIAlertView`.